# How to check for a value of ** in IF() in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel worksheet and I'm trying to use a formula to conditionally set the value of one column based on the value of another column.

I have two columns:

- Original text (text)
- Processed text (formula)

Original text contains text in markdown format.  Some of the text is **bolded** with two asterixes.

Now, in my processed text column, I want to detect `**` and either return the original text if `**` is present, or wrap the whole text in `**` if no `**` is present.

For example:

- `apple` -> `**apple**`
- `**apple**` -> `**apple` (no change)

Here's my formula:

`=IF(SEARCH("~*~*"+A2)+A2+"**"&A2&"**")`

*Note: My system uses `+` as the delimiter instead of the more common `,`.*

I'm using `~` to escape the `*`, which is a wildcard character.

The problem is that if `SEARCH()` is false, I get `#VALUE!`:

[image: example spreadsheet]

So how can I replace for the string `**` in `SEARCH()`?

Windows 11, Office 365

Comment: Please [edit] the post & share some original Data (the Screen Shot) what U have tried so far will help us to fix the issue ☺

Comment: @RajeshSinha Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495#:%7E:text=If%20the%20value%20of%20find_text%20is%20not%20found%2C%20the%20%23VALUE!%20error%20value%20is%20returned):

> If the value of find_text is not found, the #VALUE! error value is returned

When the `*` is not present in the text, you get `#VALUE!` because the `*` is not found. Change your formula to:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("~*",A4)),"**"&A4&"**",A4)
```

`ISERROR` function will return `TRUE` if an error is found (in your case `#VALUE`). So the whole formula adds `**` if there is an error. If not, it returns the cell's value.